# How to get value inside GridView?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a `timestamp` column, and I simply want to format it. In GridView I have the following:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'timestamp',
    'filter' => false,
    'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
         // How to get current timestamp value here???
    }
],
```

Documentation says, `$model` and `$column` both return objects, but I still could not find methods that provide column's data. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call any attribute through getter in closure using `$model` and that will return attribute for current model (according to row in GridView):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'timestamp',
    'filter' => false,
    'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
        return $model->timestamp;
    }
],
```

Obviously such `return` doesn't make any sense, but you can format it somehow you want. There are some built-in options for date / datetime formatting in Yii2, you can check them in official docs here:

- [Formatter asDate()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDate%28%29-detail)
- [Formatter asDateTime()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDate%28%29-detail)

Comment: Glad to help. Updated the answer with some details about built-in tools for formatting dates in Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following with Yii 1:

```
 [
        'attribute' => 'timestamp',
        'filter' => false,
        'value' => 'Custom::formatDateTime($data->date_stamp)',
    ],
```

Obviously formatDateTime is a custom method I created.